# I can't display the content of an object Promise (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new in react and I have a problem.
When I choose an option in select, I want to display this option's data with innerHTML. When I do console.log(data) I get data from my request. But, on my page I get [object Promise] or [object Object] and not the data.
I'm on it since a few weeks and I can't do it, please help me !

PS: sorry for my english, I'm French :).

Here, my code in jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Select from "../../components/forms/Select";

class Persons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            render: false,
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            persons: [],
            person: [],
            id: ''
        };
        //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    fetchPersons() {
        return axios .get("'http://localhost:8000/api/persons")
            //.then(res => res)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("result: ",result);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    persons: result.data["hydra:member"]
                })
            }),
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                })
                console.log(error);
            }
    }

    async fetchPerson(id) {
        console.log(id);
        try {
            return await fetch("'http://localhost:8000/api/persons/" + id)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log("rr " + result); //object Object
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        person: result.data
                    })
                    console.log("result1: ",result);
                    return result;
                })
        }catch(error) {
            this.setState({
                error
            })
            console.log("Erreur: ", error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPersons();
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const show = document.getElementById("show");
        console.log("I'm in handleChange");
        const value = event.target.value;
        let select = this.fetchPerson(value);
        console.log("Select: " + select);
        console.log("Select2: " , [select]);
        console.log("Select: " + [{select}]);
        console.log("Select2: " , [{select}]);
        let newContent =  "You selected " + JSON.stringify([{select}]);
        show.innerHTML = newContent;
    }

    render() {
        const {error, isLoaded, persons, person} = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <div>Erreur : {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Chargement…</div>;
        } else {

            return (
                <div id="show">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <Select id="selectPerson" name="persons"  label="Persons" value={persons.id} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                        <option key={0} value={null}>Choice</option>
                        {this.state.persons && this.state.persons.map(person => (
                            <option key={person.id} value={person.id}>{person.ref} </option>
                        ))}
                    </Select>

                    {this.state.persons && this.state.persons.map(person =>
                        <tr key={person.id}>
                            <td>{person.lname}</td>
                            <td>{person.fname}</td>
                            <td>{person.sexe}</td>
                            <td>{person.age}</td>
                        </tr>)}
                </div>
            )

        }
    }

};

export default Persons;
```

Comment: Do result.data and see. Seems like you are accessing data in wrong way. Otherwise also show console.log().

Comment: I try it now and it's returns null. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchPerson` function is `async` but your `handleChange` function does not wait for it.

```
handleChange = (event) => { // <-------- Need to make this function async
        const show = document.getElementById("show");
        console.log("I'm in handleChange");
        const value = event.target.value;
        let select = this.fetchPerson(value); // <----------- Need to wait on this with await
        console.log("Select: " + select);
        console.log("Select2: " , [select]);
        console.log("Select: " + [{select}]);
        console.log("Select2: " , [{select}]);
        let newContent =  "You selected " + JSON.stringify([{select}]);
        show.innerHTML = newContent;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , it's working ! You're fantastic :) But do you know how can I just display the value of my key without display the key ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your url, and the `fetch` fails and so you go to the `catch` part of the code which returns nothing, so since the function is `async` you get a promise.

The error is the `'` at the start of the url

```
return await fetch("'http://localhost:8000/api/persons/" + id)
                    ^
```